# How to use Union on QueryDSL 4.1.x

Tags: querydsl

I'm couldn't find any documentation on how to use union on queryDSL 4.1.x.

I need a simple query like:

```
select a, b from t1
union
select a, b from t2
```

I already have this:

```
private QCorpDimFuncionalProgramatica funcional = QCorpDimFuncionalProgramatica.corpDimFuncionalProgramatica;

JPASQLQuery<ProgramaEAcaoDTO> query = new JPASQLQuery<>(this.entityManager, sqlTemplate);

        query.select(new QProgramaEAcaoDTO(funcional.codAcao, funcional.descAcao, Expressions.constant("Ação")))
             .from(funcional);
```

and now i need to union this query with:

```
JPASQLQuery<ProgramaEAcaoDTO> query2 = new JPASQLQuery<>(this.entityManager, sqlTemplate);

        query2.select(new QProgramaEAcaoDTO(funcional.codPrograma, funcional.descPrograma, Expressions.constant("Programa")))
             .from(funcional);
```

PS: I'm using JPASQLQuery